# Set AudioAttributes Volume

Tags: notifications, android-5.0-lollipop, volume, android-audiomanager

After searching for a *very* long time for a way to play notification noises *only* through the headphones (when plugged in), on a stream separate from `STREAM_MUSIC`, in a way that could interrupt and be completely audible over any background music, Android finally came out with the AudioAttributes API. By using the following code, I'm able to achieve exactly what I want for notifications, at least in API 21 or higher (`STREAM_MUSIC` is the best option I've found for lower versions):

```
AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
    .build();
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any way to adjust the volume of the sonification in my app's settings. I currently use the `AudioManager` in the following way, but it only allows volume adjustments to streams, and none of `STREAM_ALARM`, `STREAM_NOTIFICATION`, `STREAM_RING`, or `STREAM_MUSIC` applies to whatever routing strategy is used for the sonification:

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, originalVolume, 0);
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to set the volume corresponding to the `AudioAttributes` output? Keep in mind that the audio is actually played in a `BroadcastReceiver` that's used for the actual notification, and the audio setting would be specified in just some settings `Activity`.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it appears that I missed a critical table in the API documentation:
https://source.android.com/devices/audio/attributes.html

It seems that `STREAM_SYSTEM` is the equivalent of what I was attempting to do with `AudioAttributes`. Basically, using the code I have above is sufficient for API 21 and forward, and use of `STREAM_SYSTEM` does everything necessary for the `AudioManager` and APIs prior to 21.